# Excel VBA combine rows without loss

Tags: vba, excel, basic

I need to cycle through rows on an excel sheet then combine them. Basically I am comparing the rows 1 at a time, and if they meet the argument I merge (combine?) them.

I want to make it where if the data matches we do nothing, if there is a null we fill the gap, and if the data is different concatenate it with a comma separator. Below is my section of code I am struggling with.

The argument I am referring to in the paragraph above is the if statement in my code. I want to see if the cell ticket number matches the cell's value below it, and if the cell date matches the cell's value below it. If both of those values match then I want to merge the data as elegantly as possible.

I want this

[image: start excel sheet]

To become

[image: this]

```
 For i = 2 To myRows.Count

'compare the current row to the one below it while matches are found. if the row under it is no longer a match then exit the loop

Do While doneComparing = False
        
If Cells(i, ticketNumberCell.Column).Value = Cells(i, ticketNumberCell.Column).Offset(1, 0).Value And Cells(i, dateCell.Column).Value = Cells(i, dateCell.Column).Offset(1, 0).Value Then
    'in here we merge, above we do our comparison
    'the below code is exceptionally slow. we need to speed it up or else this will not work.


'find a another way to merge since this doesnt do correctly anyway. The if statement is fine
    
'               For b = 1 To ColumnsCount
'                   Cells(i, b).Value = Cells(i, b).Offset(1, 0).Value '+ Cells(i, b).Value
'               Next
'                Rows(i).Offset(1, 0).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'
' Else
'     doneComparing = True
               
  End If
  Loop

'reset the flag for the next row
    doneComparing = False
    
  Next i
```

Comment: How I'd go about this: 1.) [Make a class](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5357/object-oriented-vba) for your rows with a property for each of the columns.  2.) Combine all the that *won't combine* properties into a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). 3.) Read the rows into a [Scripting.Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3667/scripting-dictionary-object) with the hash as the key. 4.) Check for the hashed key, and combine non-hashed properties with matches.  5.) Write the whole thing back to the Worksheet at once.

Comment: What does *"if they meet the argument "* mean?  What are the circumstances that should result in merging two different rows?

Comment: With `king` county, you have two different `codes` (or one absent and one present), but you are merging the rows anyway.  Your results suggest you should be merging columns that are not identical, but where the `county` and `date` are the same.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Sorry for the confusion Ron. I deleted my comments, and changed my post to reflect the mistake you caught. What I want to do is compare the ticket number cell to the one under it, and date cell to the one under it. If both having matching values then I want to combine the data into one row as elegantly as possible. Good catch. sorry for the incorrect info.

Comment: @Comintern I see what your saying, but I still don't think I am getting it completely. Could you post an example?

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick and dirty sample of what I was referring to in the comment above. I have no idea what the data represent, so I just called the class "RenameMe". This is the boiler-plate code for the class properties:

```
'In RenameMe.cls
Option Explicit

Private mCounty As String
Private mDate As Date
Private mCode As String
Private mDescription As String
Private mTicket As String
Private mType As String

Public Property Let County(inValue As String)
    mCounty = inValue
End Property

Public Property Get County() As String
    County = mCounty
End Property

Public Property Let RecordDate(inValue As Date)
    mDate = inValue
End Property

Public Property Get RecordDate() As Date
    RecordDate = mDate
End Property

Public Property Let Code(inValue As String)
    mCode = inValue
End Property

Public Property Get Code() As String
    Code = mCode
End Property

Public Property Let Description(inValue As String)
    mDescription = inValue
End Property

Public Property Get Description() As String
    Description = mDescription
End Property

Public Property Let Ticket(inValue As String)
    mTicket = inValue
End Property

Public Property Get Ticket() As String
    Ticket = mTicket
End Property

Public Property Let RecordType(inValue As String)
    mType = inValue
End Property

Public Property Get RecordType() As String
    RecordType = mType
End Property
```

Since you are treating the ticket and date as the critera for a distinct record, this is a simple "hash" function that generates a unique key based on that:

```
'Also in RenameMe.cls
Public Property Get Hash() As String
    Hash = Ticket & CLng(Date)
End Property
```

And finally methods for loading, and combining:

```
'Also in RenameMe.cls
Public Sub LoadRecord(sheet As Worksheet, loadRow As Long)
    County = sheet.Cells(loadRow, 1).Value
    RecordDate = sheet.Cells(loadRow, 2).Value
    Code = sheet.Cells(loadRow, 3).Value
    Description = sheet.Cells(loadRow, 4).Value
    Ticket = sheet.Cells(loadRow, 5).Value
    RecordType = sheet.Cells(loadRow, 6).Value
End Sub

Public Sub WriteRecord(sheet As Worksheet, writeRow As Long)
    sheet.Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = County
    sheet.Cells(writeRow, 2).Value = RecordDate
    sheet.Cells(writeRow, 3).Value = Code
    sheet.Cells(writeRow, 4).Value = Description
    sheet.Cells(writeRow, 5).Value = Ticket
    sheet.Cells(writeRow, 6).Value = RecordType
End Sub

Public Sub CombineWith(other As RenameMe)
    If Code <> other.Code Then
        Code = Code & "," & other.Code
    End If
    If Description <> other.Description Then
        Description = Description & "," & other.Description
    End If
    If County <> other.County Then
        County = County & "," & other.County
    End If
    If RecordType <> other.RecordType Then
        RecordType = RecordType & "," & other.RecordType
    End If
End Sub
```

The actual code that performs the work just loads the rowset into a Dictionary with the hash as keys, and then combines the ones where the keys match an existing record:

```
'In a module
Public Sub CombineRecords()
    Dim data As Worksheet
    Dim records As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Set data = ActiveSheet
    Dim i As Long, record As RenameMe
    For i = 2 To data.Range("A" & data.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set record = New RenameMe
        record.LoadRecord data, i
        If records.Exists(record.Hash) Then
            records.Item(record.Hash).CombineWith record
        Else
            records.Add record.Hash, record
        End If
    Next

    'Output to new sheet. Can easily wipe the current data
    'and replace too.
    Set data = data.Parent.Worksheets.Add

    Dim key As Variant
    i = 1
    For Each key In records
        records.Item(key).WriteRecord data, i
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much i am going to attempt this in the morning and I will get back if it works. This is much clearer now.

Comment: @alphamalle - Forgot to mention you need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  It's in the Tool->References... menu. Scroll way down to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat different approach.  The "unique rows" are stored in a Dictionary, but we also use Dictionaries within the class to store multiple items if they should be kept on the same row.  And then put those items together, in a comma separated string, when we are done.

Also, by using this method, there is no need for the rows to be sorted beforehand.

One could use the built-in VBA `Collection` object, but I think, especially with this many collections, that the coding is a bit simpler with the `Dictionary`.

We combine the two items determining uniqueness `Date` and `TicketNumber` as the `key`.

Note you need to rename the Class Module:  `cRows` and that you must also add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

### Class Module

```
Option Explicit

'Rename to cRows

Private pDT As Date
Private pTicket As String

Private pCounty As String
Private pCounties As Dictionary

Private pCode As String
Private pCodes As Dictionary

Private pDescription As String
Private pDescriptions As Dictionary

Private pTyp As String
Private pTyps As Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'use dictionaries to combine multiple items
    Set pCounties = New Dictionary
    Set pCodes = New Dictionary
    Set pDescriptions = New Dictionary
    Set pTyps = New Dictionary
End Sub

Public Property Get DT() As Date
    DT = pDT
End Property
Public Property Let DT(Value As Date)
    pDT = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Ticket() As String
    Ticket = pTicket
End Property
Public Property Let Ticket(Value As String)
    pTicket = Value
End Property

Public Property Get County() As String
    County = pCounty
End Property
Public Property Let County(Value As String)
    pCounty = Value
End Property
Public Property Get Counties() As Dictionary
    Set Counties = pCounties
End Property
Public Function ADDCounty(Value As String)
    If Value <> "" Then
        If Not pCounties.Exists(Value) Then _
        pCounties.Add Key:=Value, Item:=Value
    End If
End Function

Public Property Get Code() As String
    Code = pCode
End Property
Public Property Let Code(Value As String)
    pCode = Value
End Property
Public Property Get Codes() As Dictionary
    Set Codes = pCodes
End Property
Public Function ADDCode(Value As String)
    If Value <> "" Then
        If Not pCodes.Exists(Value) Then _
        pCodes.Add Value, Value
    End If
End Function


Public Property Get Description() As String
    Description = pDescription
End Property
Public Property Let Description(Value As String)
    pDescription = Value
End Property
Public Property Get Descriptions() As Dictionary
    Set Descriptions = pDescriptions
End Property
Public Function ADDDescription(Value As String)
    If Value <> "" Then
        If Not pDescriptions.Exists(Value) Then _
        pDescriptions.Add Value, Value
    End If
End Function

Public Property Get Typ() As String
    Typ = pTyp
End Property
Public Property Let Typ(Value As String)
    pTyp = Value
End Property
Public Property Get Typs() As Dictionary
    Set Typs = pTyps
End Property
Public Function ADDTyp(Value As String)
    If Value <> "" Then
        If Not pTyps.Exists(Value) Then _
        pTyps.Add Value, Value
    End If
End Function

Public Function CombineDicts(Dict As Dictionary) As String
    Dim W As Variant, S As String

    For Each W In Dict
        S = S & "," & Dict(W)
    Next W
    CombineDicts = Mid(S, 2)
End Function
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit

'Add Reference (Tools/References) to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Sub DeDupAndCombine()
    Dim cR As cRows, dR As Dictionary
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, V As Variant, W As Variant
    Dim sKey As String

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'Get the Source data
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=6)
End With

'collect and dedup
Set dR = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set cR = New cRows
    With cR
        .DT = vSrc(I, 2)
        .Ticket = vSrc(I, 5)
        sKey = .DT & "|" & .Ticket

        .County = vSrc(I, 1)
        .ADDCounty .County

        .Code = vSrc(I, 3)
        .ADDCode .Code

        .Description = vSrc(I, 4)
        .ADDDescription .Description

        .Typ = vSrc(I, 6)
        .ADDTyp .Typ

        If Not dR.Exists(sKey) Then
            dR.Add sKey, cR
        Else
            With dR(sKey)
                .ADDCounty cR.County
                .ADDCode cR.Code
                .ADDDescription cR.Description
                .ADDTyp cR.Typ
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next I

'Create the results
ReDim vRes(0 To dR.Count, 1 To 6)

'Headers
For I = 1 To 6
    vRes(0, I) = vSrc(1, I)
Next I

'data
I = 0
For Each V In dR
    I = I + 1
    With dR(V)
        vRes(I, 1) = .CombineDicts(.Counties)
        vRes(I, 2) = .DT
        vRes(I, 3) = .CombineDicts(.Codes)
        vRes(I, 4) = .CombineDicts(.Descriptions)
        vRes(I, 5) = .Ticket
        vRes(I, 6) = .CombineDicts(.Typs)
    End With
Next V

'Write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

If speed is an issue, you could experiment to see if executing the `.RemoveDuplicates` method results in any faster execution time.  You could also turn off `ScreenUpdating` before the segment that writes to the worksheet.